# independence of gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent centered gaussians with variance 1. How can one compute the law $\frac{Y}{X}\mathbb{1}_{X\neq 0}$? Is there a general way to do this for any two independent random variables or is this something that is computable only exploiting the fact that $Y$ and $X$ are gaussians?

Comment: If you don't have more informations on the joint distribution, you can't compute the law of $Y/X$.

Comment: But mean 0, variance 1 gaussians and independence should be sufficient, right?

Comment: Sorry, independence is enough, indeed (I misread it your past). Then, $$\mathbb P\left\{\frac{Y}{X}\leq z\right\}=\mathbb P\{Y\leq Xz\}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_{\{(x,y)\mid y\leq xz\}}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y.$$ I let you finish.

Comment: Thanks, how do I take the indicator function of $X$ not being $0$ into account?

Comment: $\boldsymbol 1_{X=0}$ is a null set, this mean that $\mathbb P\{\frac{Y}{X}\boldsymbol 1_{X\neq 0}=\frac{Y}{X}\}=1$. Therefore, $\mathbb P\{\frac{Y}{X}\boldsymbol 1_{X\neq 0}\leq z\}=\mathbb P\{\frac{Y}{X}\leq z\}$.